comparing two meshes c++ "libigl"
I would like to compare the similarity of Nodes and Faces from the first mesh with the second mesh by using libel and Eigen
how could I do it?
I do not have any Idea how to start
please if you know of any paper to compare the two meshes mention it

Could you add some details, what do you want to compare ? how are your meshes represented in memory ?

Given that two meshes can have a very different number of vertices, different scale and orientation, I guess first of all you would need to find a certain orientation/translation/scale that would align two meshes as close as possible.
I would suggest to find them using optimization algorithm, e.g. L-BFGS, by minimizing the distance between each vertex on one mesh with the nearest N vertices on the second mesh.
After the alignment is found, you can estimate similarity of vertices and faces with whatever metric you find useful. E.g. you can reuse the metric you use for alignment - the average distance between vertex on one mesh and nearest vertices on another mesh. Alternatively, you can also consider areas of triangles, orientation of triangles, etc
